# How to duplicate a movement construct of one element to another? JavaScript

Tags: javascript

Below is an example of a box moving left,right,up or down based 
on pressing the arrow keys. However when I added a "*laser*" and used 
the exact same principal/code to move the laser from left to right using "*laserLeft++*;" with the space bar, it does not move. I have very 
carefully duplicated the code from the "square" to apply to the laser and 
I cannot find why there is no movement. (I did not copy and paste the entire view source since it isn't relevant to problem).

the specific function is question is **fireLaser()**.

```
#square {
position: absolute;
top: 0px;
left: 0px;
height: 5px;
width: 5px;
background-color: white;
}
#laser {
postion: absolute;
top: 0px;
left 0px;
height: 2px;
width: 5px;
background-color: red;
}

<script>
document.addEventListener("keydown", keyBoardInput);

var boxTop = 0;
var boxLeft = 0;
var laserTop = 0;
var laserLeft = 0;


function moveBoxUp(){
var square = document.getElementById("square");
boxTop--; 
square.style.top = boxTop;

};
function moveBoxDown(){
var square = document.getElementById("square");
boxTop++;
square.style.top = boxTop;

};
function moveBoxLeft(){
var square = document.getElementById("square");
boxLeft--;
square.style.left = boxLeft;

};
function moveBoxRight(){
var square = document.getElementById("square");
boxLeft++;
square.style.left = boxLeft;

};
function fireLaser(){
var laser = document.getElementById("laser");
laserLeft++;
laser.style.left = laserLeft;   
};

var i = event.keyCode;
if(i == 38){
moveBoxUp();
};

if(i == 40){
moveBoxDown();
};

if(i == 37){
moveBoxLeft();
};

if(i == 39){
moveBoxRight();
};

if (i == 32){
fireLaser();
};

};
</script>
```

Comment: Where is you function `keyBoardInput`? You need to do `function keyBoardInput(event){ var i = event.keyCode; if(i == 38){moveBoxUp();};...};`

Comment: its above my declared variables, under the script tag

Comment: I dont see it anywhere declared, i used the "CTRL+F" to search for it. You only added `keyBoardInput` as `click-EventListener` to the element. But not declared it in the above snippet.

Comment: look towards the bottom: if (i == 32){
    fireLaser();
    }; this code activates the fireLaser() function everytime the space bar is pressed

Comment: its still not working i added a ":" to the css and a window.alert to makse sure the firelaser() functioned is actualy being called but the laser wount move

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found my error!!! it was incorrectly typed "postion: absolute;" now it works perfectly!!!

Comment: Still my question: Where did you declare the function `keyBoardInput`?

Comment: the keyBoardInput is setup: document.addEventListener("keydown", keyBoardInput); and then with: var i = event.keyCode; it tells the browser anytime a key (if (i == 32){
fireLaser();
};) is pressed to activate the fireLaser() function.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/4xka0wow/ look at your posted Code, there is a `};` to much. The `function keyBoardInput` is never declared in your code snippet. Yes you add the `not declared function` to the `keydown`-event. But never declare the function itself. When i remove the `};` it shows the error: `keyBoardInput is not defined` https://jsfiddle.net/4xka0wow/1/. No i added the declaration of the `keyBoardInput`function and have no errors: https://jsfiddle.net/4xka0wow/2/